# Magazine style grid with Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, grid-layout

I want to make a magazine style website and preferably with Bootstrap (if that's possible). I want it to look like this:
[image]

Can anyone tell me if it's possible to make something like this with Bootstrap? If not maybe someone can tell me if there is a good alternative. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make it like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You may have to set height for the col-sm-8's to make it look exactly same.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I'll take a look at it

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap Grid is used to create fluid layout uses a series of containers, rows, and columns to layout and align content.
In these example the html layout can look as follow.

```
 <style>
.box{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}
.left{
    float: left;
 }
 .right{
    float: right;
 }
</style>
<div class="row">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 box">

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 box"></div>
  </div> 
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-8 right box">

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 right box">

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 left box">

    </div>
  </div> 
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 box">

    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Almost all of your CSS can be replaced with built-in classes in Bootstrap.